# OnMouseWheel event with MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, event-handling

I am having some problems with the ON_WM_MOUSEWHEEL event and MFC. The function handling the event does get called, but not when scrolling, just when "pinching" the touchpad. Is it supposed to behave like this?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7.

Comment: Since a touchpad doesn't actually contain a wheel, what are you expecting? I'm being serious here - what actions do you expect to trigger a WM_MOUSEWHEEL message?

Comment: Do you mean that the `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` message is not sent when using the scroll wheel on a scroll mouse? Because *it works for me*.

Comment: I am using a touchpad which allows me to scroll pages using two fingers. When doing this in my application, the cursor changes to indicate that I am scrolling vertically. I can capture this event with a mouseWheelListener in java AWT, so it seems strange that it should not be possible in MFC.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that some touchpad drivers implement scrolling using the WM_VSCROLL message, however since the java AWT's mouseWheelListener is working, my recommendation would be:

Open Spy++ and verify whether or not WM_MOUSEWHEEL messages are being posted.

If messages are not being posted the control might not have focus.

If messages are being posted, it might be a problem with the way the control is attempting to receive the message. In this case, showing us the message map might help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [WM_TOUCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317341%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.

Comment: No, that requires special initialization.  WM_GESTURE would be a better guess.